# Tension at any point of a hanging rope

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, mass, string, continuum-mechanics

A common question to those initial practitioners of classical mechanics it to find the tension of a rope hanging between two trees, at the end and the middle. Below a graphical description of the situation.  The answer to this problem is well known and it is
$$
T_{\text{end}} = \frac{mg}{2 \sin \theta_{\text{end}}}, \quad T_{\text{middle}} = \frac{mg}{2 \tan \theta_{\text{end}}}. 
$$

[image]

A more interesting problem is to find the tension at any point of the rope, because it let us know the shape, in geometrical terms, of a hanging rope.

Answer (score 2):

To face this problem we can use a parametric curve representation of the rope $\gamma(s) = (x(s), y(s))$ where $s$ is the arc-length parameter. Suppose the rope has total lenght $L$ and we start to measure the length from the middle of the rope, so at the end of the rope we have $\lvert s \rvert = L/2$.
Since $\gamma$ is unit-speed we can write its tangent vector as $\dot{\gamma}(s) = (\cos \theta(s),\sin \theta(s))$ where $\theta(s)$ is the angle that the tangent vector makes with the horizontal, known in mathematics as the turning angle. This turning angle plays an important role in the geometry of the curve $\gamma$ in the sense that its derivative determine the form of the curve. More precisely, the derivative of the turning angle is the signed curvature of the rope,
$$
k_{s} = \frac{d \theta}{ds},
$$
and the fundamental theorem of curves stablishes that curves with the same signed curvature are the same up to a rigid motion (or an isometry of the plane).

[image]

As usual, to find the tension at any point $\gamma(s)$ we analize the forces on small piece of rope with endpoints $\gamma(s+\Delta s)$ and $\gamma(s)$. So, the equations of motion of this section of rope are
$$
\begin{align}
T(s+\Delta s)\cos \theta(s+\Delta s) - T(s)\cos \theta(s) &= 0\\
T(s + \Delta s) \sin \theta(s + \Delta s) - T(s)\sin \theta (s) &= \frac{m\Delta s}{L}g
\end{align}
$$
Dividing these two equations by $\Delta s$ and taking the limit as $\Delta s \to 0$ we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{ds}\left(T(s) \cos \theta(s)\right) &= 0 \\
\frac{d}{ds}\left(T(s)\sin \theta(s)\right) &= \frac{mg}{L}
\end{align}
$$
So, $T(s) \cos \theta(s) = \lambda$ and $T(s) \sin \theta(s) =  \frac{mg}{L} s + \nu$, where $\lambda$, and $\nu$ are consntants. Since $\theta(0) = 0$, we obtain that $\nu = 0$ and that $\lambda = T(0) = T_{0}$.
Then we have the two equations
$$
\begin{align}
T(s) \cos \theta(s) &= T_{0} = T_{\text{middle}}\\
T(s) \sin \theta(s) &= \frac{mg}{L}s
\end{align}
$$
From this we obtain that
$$
\tan \theta(s) = \frac{m g}{T_{0} L}s = \frac{s}{a}
$$
where $a = (\frac{ m g}{T_{0} L})^{-1}$. If we derivate with respect to s then
$$
\sec^{2} \theta(s) \frac{d\theta}{ds} = \frac{1}{a} \implies \frac{d\theta}{ds} = \frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{\sec^{2}\theta(s)} = \frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{1+ \tan^{2}\theta(s)} = \frac{1}{a}\left(1 + \frac{s^{2}}{a^{2}}\right)^{-1}
$$
This tell us that the curvature of the rope at $\gamma(s)$ is
$$
k_{s}(s) = \frac{1}{a}\left(1 + \frac{s^{2}}{a^{2}}\right)^{-1}.
$$
To our surprise, there is a famous curve which have the same curvature known as $\textit{catenary}$, whose parametric equations may be expresed as $\gamma(t) = (t, a \cosh(t/a))$  (to get the curvature express the $\gamma$ by arc-length parameter and compute $\lvert \gamma'' (s) \rvert$). Therefore a hanging rope have the shape of a catenary.

Finally, from the equations
$$
\begin{align}
T(s) \cos \theta(s) &= T_{0}\\
T(s) \sin \theta(s) &= \frac{mg}{L}s
\end{align}
$$
we obtain that the tension at $\gamma(s)$ is
$$
T(s) = \sqrt{T_{0}^{2} +  \left(\frac{mg}{L}\right)^{2}s^{2}}
$$